# java - none of the classes is found

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After I changed the groupid of my maven project, I get `ClassNotFoundException` for all of my classes.

```
Class not found com.some.package.Test_SomeClass
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.some.package.Test_SomeClass
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:500)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:523)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:761)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:207)
```

This is the first time I experience something like this. The strange thing is that eclipse still recognizes all the classes, i.e. doesn't show compilation errors in the code. Also maven update still works.

**EDIT**

I get this error when I do `mvn clean install`

**EDIT 2**

Here is the pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.company.group</groupId>
  <!-- the maven project was created with a different groupid (com.company.anothergroup) -->
  <artifactId>project</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>aproject</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <!-- ...properties... -->
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- ...dependencies... -->
  </dependencies>

   <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus-release</id>
            <url>https://company.com/nexus/</url>
        </repository>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>https://company.com/nexus/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <scm>
       <url>company github url</url>
        <connection>connection details</connection>
        <developerConnection>connection detils</developerConnection>
    </scm>


  <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
         </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                  <source>1.8</source>
                  <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: What do you do to see this error? Have you tried to clean and build the project again?

Comment: show the pom.xml...

Comment: Are the Test classes in the same project or in a different one? Does the test project have a dependency on the artifact under test, and is the group id there set correctly?

Comment: when trying again this morning it just worked again. maybe an Eclipse glitch.